# Ajax jquery write data to document; Open data in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, new-window

How to write any type if data to html DOM document;

I do it like this:

```
var w = window.open("./results.html", "", "width=800, height=900");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './execute',
    data: {
         "id": 99,
         "name": XYZ
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        w.document.write(data);
        w.hideProgress();
        w.document.close();
        w.focus();
    }
});
```

I would like to open html, xml, zip files in new window but before that i count time to see how many time is spend on request and showing progress bar.

But as i see document.write() support only html, and string.

So how to write any type of data in new window and during request show progress bar and timecount.

Comment: What do you mean " how to write any type of data in new window"?? how do you write a zip file in an html document? :/

Comment: actullay i get response from server that need to start download zip file. So i just want to get zip file start downloaded. So i stuck that cannot handle all data types with ajax request. If a submit the same request from form the browser handle all type but how to do this with ajax